# RoR & coffeescript: unexpected (

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I can't see what is wrong with my code. It seems like a weird error to throw. See [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24%28%22.category_modal%22%29.click%20%28e%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Hi%22%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%24.ajax%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20url%3A%20%27entries%2Fdetail%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22GET%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dataType%3A%20%27json%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20success%3A%20%28data%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Hi%20again%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%22.category_modal%22%29.html%28data%29) for the code in a "try coffeescript" compiler.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#swipes').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post( $(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable.('serialize') )
```

The error reads:

```
Error on line 5: unexpected (
```

Comment: I'd say `$(this).sortable.('serialize')` - notice the **dot** before `('serialize')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is a syntax error because on line 5 you are writing

```
$(this).sortable.('serialize')
```

But there is an extra `.` in there causing the error. Try;

```
$(this).sortable('serialize')
```

Because of the extra `.` the compiler can't recognise the function.

Hope that helps!